# Making multiple AJAX calls from the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have two buttons, which when they are clicked, an ajax to the same page is made.
Here's the simple ajax code from the two functions.

Code Snippet

```js
function sayName(name) {
    
       
                $.ajax({ data: {'var1' : name}, type: 'post', success: function(result){
                
                location.reload(true);
                }});
                
                
        } 
  
  
  
function sayFolder(folder) {                
                $.ajax({ data: {'var2' : folder}, type: 'post', success: function(result){
                
                location.reload(true);
                }});
                
                
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='button' name='folder1' onclick='sayName(this.name)'> Folder 1 </button>
<button type='button' name='folder2' onclick='sayFolder(this.name)'> Folder 2 </button>
```

**PHP File**
if(!empty($_POST['var1'])) {

```
     echo($_POST['var1']);
   
 

}  elseif (!empty($_POST['var2'])) {
    echo($_POST['var2']);
    
}
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in your code (missing closing quote in `empty($_POST['var2]`). Is this an actual error or just one that you made when transferring the code into the question?

Comment: Just a typo error, transfering the code, thanks... @El_Vanja

Comment: How exactly do you determine if the function executed correctly or not? I don't see you using `result` anywhere.

Comment: The function is executed using the ``onclick`` of the button, I have tested on my site and it returns the variable... The problem resides on the first AJAX call, where it seems like it does not clear correctly and the PHP code can't take a new AJAX call.

Comment: You are reloading in the success handler, so if you trigger the first button and the call completes before the second AJAX is finished, it will never receive the response, since you reloaded the page.

Comment: I see, I have made the AJAX call from the second function to another page and it executes correctly. So the same page is misbehaving with the AJAX code, do you know how to clean all AJAX variables when the first func is finished?

Comment: "Clean AJAX variables" makes no sense. Each of those is a separate request. I believe your issue is with reloading. May I ask why do you even use AJAX if your goal is to refresh the page?

Comment: Well, @El_Vanja I think you are right, I will remove the AJAX calls and try to work it out from another perspective. Thanks :)